# PHP Hyperlinks does not work as variables

Tags: php, html, mysql, hyperlink

I'm a beginner in PHP so may be asking dumb questions. I researched on my question for couple of days prior to bugging you guys. I've two scenarios.

a) MySQL database has 3 fields. `description`, `weblink` and `header`. "weblink" field stores weblinks in the database. Using PHP I'm trying to show weblinks on my webpage upon the user clicking the field "header".Its not working- webpage comes blank with the code below.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){   
     echo $row['description'];
     echo "<br>";
     echo "<br>";
     echo "<a href = $row['weblink'] > $row['Header']</a>";
     echo "<br>";
     echo "<hr>";
}
```

b) Scenario 2: Same example from above but trying to show the links from my database as a button.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){   
     echo $row['description'];
     echo "<br>";
     echo "<br>";
     echo $row['weblink'];
     echo "<br>";
     <a href = "$row['weblink']"<button>click me</button></a>;
     echo "<hr>";
}
```

Please help.

Comment: 1. your code is broken. 2. you never close the href tag.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The brackets in the echo are treated as a string not as an array key So use { } these brackets.Also your quotes are not proper. Use the code below

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){   
echo $row['description'];
echo "<br>";
echo "<br>";
echo "<a href =' {$row['weblink']}' > {$row['Header']}</a>";
echo "<br>";
echo "<hr>";}
```

Scenario 2

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){   
echo $row['description'];
echo "<br>";
echo "<br>";
echo $row['weblink'];
echo "<br>";
echo '<a href = "{$row['weblink']}"><button>click me</button></a>';
echo "<hr>";}
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: Thanks Hudixt! You guys here are so helpful and awesome! My problem is solved. I did not know that variables needed to be enclosed in braces for echo statements.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the humble [`printf()`](http://php.net/printf) instead and apply proper **output escaping**:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    printf('%s<br><br><a href="%s">%s</a><br><hr>',
        htmlspecialchars($row['description'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'),
        htmlspecialchars($row['weblink'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'),
        htmlspecialchars($row['Header'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

for Scenario 1, You should do something like this (note the braces):

```
echo "<a href='{$row['weblink']}'>{$row['Header']}</a>";
```

For scenario 2, you should do something like this (again note braces):

```
echo "<a href=\"{$row['weblink']}\"><button>click me</button></a>";
```

Remember that Braces work on variables that are within double quotes, and not apostrophes.

Comment: Thanks The Boogie Man! For scenario 2, I used your method and it worked great.

Comment: Hey, would you know how I can open the link on another tab of the browser when a user clicks the button?

Comment: add `target="blank"` to the link

Comment: Tried this but looks like I'm messing up somewhere-echo "<a href=\"{$row['weblink']}\"><button type="submit" formtarget="_blank">click me</button></a>";

Comment: you need a space between items. you have `formtarget` put a space between the two

Comment: Sorry friend, I keep coming back to you. Tried different things for couple of days but this just does not work for me. Please help.echo "<a href=\"{$row['weblink']}\"><button type="submit" form target="_blank">click me</button></a>";

Answer (score 1):

```
Check the below code:

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){   
    echo $row['description'];
    echo "<br><br>";
    echo $row['weblink'];
    echo "<br>";
    echo '<a href = "'.$row['weblink'].'" class="add-button-style">click me</a>';
    echo "<hr>";
}
```